# how to send a Photo with caption in telegram using ex3ndr?

Tags: java, telegram

I am using ex3ndr for creating a telegram client. now i want to send a message witch has a photo and a caption or description. I send photo using this code snippet:

```
 private static void sendMedia(PeerState peerState, String fileName) {
    TLAbsInputPeer inputPeer = peerState.isUser() ? new TLInputPeerContact(peerState.getId()) : new TLInputPeerChat(peerState.getId());

    int task = api.getUploader().requestTask(fileName, null);
    api.getUploader().waitForTask(task);
    int resultState = api.getUploader().getTaskState(task);
    Uploader.UploadResult result = api.getUploader().getUploadResult(task);
    TLAbsInputFile inputFile;
    if (result.isUsedBigFile()) {
        inputFile = new TLInputFileBig(result.getFileId(), result.getPartsCount(), "file.jpg");
    } else {
        inputFile = new TLInputFile(result.getFileId(), result.getPartsCount(), "file.jpg", result.getHash());
    }
    try {
        TLAbsStatedMessage res = api.doRpcCall(new TLRequestMessagesSendMedia(inputPeer, new TLInputMediaUploadedPhoto(inputFile), rnd.nextInt()), 30000);
        res.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but I donot know how can add caption to this photo?(this code snippet is a sample from this url: [ex3ndr sample](https://github.com/ex3ndr/telegram-bot/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/telegram/bot/Application.java)
)

Comment: If you need to create Telegram Bot (not client) take a look on my library. It's well documented https://github.com/pengrad/java-telegram-bot-api

Comment: thank you but i want to create Telegram Client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ex3ndr library](https://github.com/ex3ndr/telegram-api/blob/master/libs) only support layer 12 of Telegram API where [sendMedia](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.sendMedia?layer=12) method doesn't support captions in photos. That's means this library is not able to send captions with photos, the layer should be updated before being able of doing so (and the repository seems to be abandoned).

Comment: thanks for your description and helpful answer but do you have any suggestion to resolve this problem?

Comment: Currently, I'm only aware of one public library for that, [this](https://github.com/vysheng/tg) one made by Vysheng that seems to support up to layer 31.